It is impossible to implement an immutable struct type
class string is immutable. It is impossible implementing an immutable struct type as you can't disable or override assignment operation (=). Even you define a readonly struct, you can always change the value of the struct type by using assignment operator.
For example, x,y are values of a readonly struct. x = y; will change the content of x. So, the readonly struct section in C# language reference is not correct. Is this right?

What you describe about the assignment, does not mean that your struct is mutable. No, it is truly immutable. It only means that the variable x is not read-only. Make the variable read-only and be sure it cannot be modified. But then this is not about your immutable structure, but only about the type where x is a member.
So, I don't see how your question makes sense. Do I miss something?

@Sergey A Kryukov. You can read the string type.String is immutable class, the following code will create a brand-new string, and  'b' will refer to it rather than change the value 'h' to 'hello'.
'string b = "h";
b += "ello";'

readonly struct section

No, you are not right. The documentation on readonly struct is perfectly correct. Your question contains a broken link (you've fixed it in one of your comments, but it's better to modify the question), the correct URL of this documentation page and section is this.
The explanation is pretty simple. Consider this example:
    readonly struct A {
        internal A(int first, string second) { First = first; Second = second; }
        internal readonly int First { get; init; }
        internal readonly string Second { get; init; }
    }

    static class ReadonlyUsage {
        static A value = new(0, "original value");
        internal static void Demo() {
            A a = new(1, "constant value");
            //a.First = 12; // will fail to compile
            a = new(2, "another value");
            // this is mutable:
            value = new(3, "one more value");
            //value.First = 13; // will fail to compile
            // still mutable:
            value = new(4, "How much longer?!");
        }
    }

What is mutable here? Nothing except ReadonlyUsage.value, and it makes ReadonlyUsage also mutable. It has nothing to do with struct A — it is immutable. Exactly as System.String.
Let's see: what about the assignment to A a? Does this assignment make ReadonlyUsage mutable? No. You assign a new value (and struct A is a value type) to a stack variable. It exists only in the stack and will be removed after the exit of a current stack frame. The stack does not belong to the class, it belongs to the thread calling ReadonlyUsage.Demo. The assignment does not modify anything in the Demo class if it was an instance class. We simply create a new struct A instance and never modify any of the already existing instances, that's why it is called immutable.
Now, what about the assignment to ReadonlyUsage.value? It is possible, because ReadonlyUsage is mutable. Again, we create new instances of struct A and never modify any of the already existing instances.
How to prevent the assignment to ReadonlyUsage.value? Easy: make it readonly, too:
static readonly A value = new(0, "original value");


In your demo  function, if I append the following code:
 A b = new(5, "how can you explaine?");
 a = b;

Now, is a a brand-new value or just copy the value of b? If a copy the value of b, so struct A is not immutable. If you declare a with readonly modifier, a=b won't work.
Then see the string example:
'
string b = "h";
b += "ello";
'
now, 'b' is a brand-new value "hello", and "h" will be garbage collected. So, 'class string' is immutable.

@Leo qiao — Here is the answer: a and b are stack variables. And struct A is a value type. It means that the entire piece of memory is copied to the memory space reserved for a on the stack. The same happens to b. Now, what is a = b? The entire memory pattern moves from the piece occupied by a to the one of b. Where is the old content previously accessed by a? Discarded, Discarded, can you see it? Not modified, but discarded. Naturally, the object has a limited lifetime, it does not live forever.

@Leo qiao — I still have to continue. First, the instance is created. Inside a constructor, it is still mutable, but it doesn't count. It is immutable after its complete creation when it is constructed. And it is discarded. Even without a = b both a and b are discarded when the code exits the stack frame. As to ReadonlyUsage.value, it is discarded at the end of the process lifetime. If ReadonlyUsage.value is non-static, it is discarded with ReadonlyUsage instance destruction.

@Leo qiao — Now, strings. They are a lot more complicated. 1) System.String is not a value type. It is a reference type that mimics value semantics. 2) There is the intern pool. A new value is not just created. It is found in the pool. If found, it is referenced to be the new instance. If not, the new value is added to the pool and then referenced. And it is not garbage-collected the same way as other reference objects. The mechanism is more complicated. Please review my last 3 answers and see what possibly can be missing. I'll answer more if you need.

.Thanks  a lot. In your opinion, all value types are immutable. If int is immutable, the following code will change the address of x:

int x = 1;
x=2;
"will change the address of x" - no, it will write the value 2 to the variable x. Note: this does not change the value of "1", only that of "x".

@Leo qiao — “Thanks a lot. In your opinion, all value types are immutable.” No, not even close. And nothing here is in my opinion, it's in reality. Immutable value types are immutable, others are mutable. Remove all readonly stuff from struct A, change members to read-write, and you will get a mutable value type.
By the way, <pre> or <code> don't work here, use Markdown. Backslashes instead of <code>.

@Klaus Gütter — you are right, no address changes here.  For the value types, “it will write the value 2 to the variable x” means that the piece of memory itself is copied from the place occupied by one variable to the place occupied by another one.  And this is not like with strings. Can we ever explain all that to our inquirer? I thought my answer would be enough. I'm still trying...

if the address of x is not changed, its content(value) changed to 2, so, x is not immutable. x is int, so int is not immutable. what is the meaning of "discard" as you metioned above?  if the address of x is not changed, how can you put a new value in the address?

@Leo qiao — “so, x is not immutable”. These are just words. What about the meaning? We are talking about meanings. So, what is your understanding of the term immutable? Here is one hint for you: don't mix up variables and corresponding objects.  A variable cannot be mutable or immutable. It can be read-only or not, as well as a type, and that can create a confusion. Also, can a piece of memory be modified? Apparently, if you perform an operation like assignment, something may change, but not always change. Is it the same as object mutation?

@Sergey A Kryukov. According the string type, the term immutable means "you can't change the content. if you try to change the content, I will create a brand-new value with different memory address for you". Is that correct? If you discard a value, you can't use the address of this discarded value for containing a new value, because that address will be garbage-collected.

@Leo qiao — Yes, according to the string type, it is correct. As to the discarded values, garbage collections (also add the exit from a stack frame), the apparent but irrelevant contradiction can be reconciled: you need to understand that the notion of immutability or mutability, like many other properties of entities, are only applicable to the lifespan of the object. Beyond the object lifetime, before the final construction and after destruction or getting out of accessible scope, these notions are neither true nor false, they make no sense.

According the meaning of "immutable" in the string type section,  do you still think int or other value types are immutable?

@Leo qiao — “...do you still think int or other value types are immutable?” I already replied on the topic of int ++ operator, good point. Look, mutation and read-only are orthogonal concepts. An attempt to look at the relationships between them is pointless.

You can implement a readonly struct type, and declare a 'readonly' field. For example:Struct readonly MyReadonlyStruct{..}; class Whatever { readonly MyReadonlyStruct myReadStruct;}

@Leo qiao  — “You can implement a...” Why are you telling me that?! Please, let's wrap it up. You've started to talk about nothing. I've explained everything.

Sorry, I did not mean it. I want to say if I write codes above, I can not change the value of Whatever.myReadStruct and  MyReadonyStruct is readonly struc. It is the meaning of ïmmutable", is that correct?

I read an artical here. I agree with the view of its author: When we change the value of mutable objects, value is changed in same memory. But in immutable type, the new memory is created and the modified value is stored in new memory.

I found a section on Wikipedia that may explain your question:

Violating immutability
Immutability does not imply that the object as stored in the
computer's memory is unwriteable. Rather, immutability is a
compile-time construct that indicates what a programmer can do through
the normal interface of the object, not necessarily what they can
absolutely do (for instance, by circumventing the type system or
violating const correctness in C or C++).

In my own words, "Immutable" and "Assignment" are two independent concepts in C# as a programming language. "Immutable" just refers to the immutability of an object's state. The reason you think value types are mutable by reassignment is because the assignment of value types happens to overwrite the memory they are allocated. As stated on wiki, if there is a way to write the memory referenced by a string, it would also violate its immutability. (and this is really possible)

Int type provides ++ interface, which can change the value itself. So, int type is mutable.

@Leo qiao — “So, int type is mutable.” Yes. This is not a readonly struct, is it? :-)

You are right. I only have to note that the Wikipedia quote is not, strictly speaking, a proof. Not Encyclopædia Britannica, not your university textbook, nothing.  Аrgumentum ad verecundiam is not a valid argument. With the judgment about usable language, the situation is slightly different though, because it may appeal to common practice.
It's a good point about two different concepts.

The c# specification does not definitely define the meaning of "immutable". I read the string section and readonly struct section of c# specification. I think the meaning of ïmmutable" in these two sections is different.
